# Why is $('#id').click function not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, event-handling

It works perfectly on localhost but it doesn't work on the server.

When I click on the 'Start Free Trial' anchor text, it doesn't work. The alert doesn't show up. What could be the problem?

```
<script>
 $(function() {
        $('#activator3').click(function(){
            alert('huan');
            $('#overlays3').fadeIn('fast',function(){
                $('#boxs3').animate({'top':'80px'},500);
            });
        });
        $('#boxclose3').click(function(){
            $('#boxs3').animate({'top':'-500px'},500,function(){
                $('#overlays3').fadeOut('fast');
            });
         });

    });
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="" class="activator3" id="activator3">
<div id="indexpack2" style="">Start Free Trial</div>
</a>
```

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anjandash/oboLfrxc/)**

---

#### Note

I have tried:

1. adding `document.ready()` to wrap the script - not working
2. `$('#activator3').on('click', function(){});`  - not working

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: SOLVED by adding JQUERY

Comment: works fine if you add jquery first https://jsfiddle.net/oboLfrxc/1/

Comment: Hi, I have seen your jsfiddle Code, There is one option <JAVASCRIPT> with Setting Icon, Please select jQuery as Library. There is no library loaded in your code. as you can see firebug console you will get following error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Check here updated: https://jsfiddle.net/anjandash/oboLfrxc/

Comment: @AshwinP Yes, I forgot to include the Jquery lib in my fiddle. Apologies works just fine! Thanks. :)

Comment: @BenG thank you! Silly me. :/

Comment: Is these problems in a specific browser? or all browsers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are missing Jquery reference. Include below code in your file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So silly of me - simple things are the hardest to catch. Thank you @maulik sakhare

Comment: its my pleasure to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you load jQuery before your JS?

Should work.

```
<a href="#" style="" class="activator3" id="activator3">
  <div id="indexpack2" style="">Start Free Trial</div>
</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
   $('#activator3').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     alert('huan');

   });
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4z871dp2/1/

Comment: I forgot to include the Jquery lib. Thank you @Pimskie.

Answer (score 1):

In your Fiddle, you forgot to add jQuery, and you put your JavaScript code at the wrong place.

If you fix those two things, your code works just fine!

---

#### Demo

```js
$(function() {
    $('#activator3').click(function(){
        alert('huan');
        $('#overlays3').fadeIn('fast',function(){
            $('#boxs3').animate({'top':'80px'},500);
        });
    });
    $('#boxclose3').click(function(){
        $('#boxs3').animate({'top':'-500px'},500,function(){
            $('#overlays3').fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="" class="activator3" id="activator3"><div id="indexpack2" style="">Start Free Trial</div></a>
```

(See also [**the fixed Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/oboLfrxc/3/))